# Is it possible to install multiple Interactive agents on a single machine?

Tags: azure-devops

I know it is possible to install several agents running as a service on a single machine, but  Is it possible to install multiple Interactive agents on a single machine?

OS: Win Server 2016
TFS 2018

Comment: Yes. Did you *try* it? It would have taken you less time to test this scenario out than to receive this answer.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, i tried installing 2 interactive agents on the same server. One interactive agent worked fine on a single machine, but when i tried installing a second one, it disabled the first one. I wasn't sure if this was supported, hence my question. I would appreciate if you "un-down vote" my question. Thanks for your comment :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of research and trial and error, finally found out that you can only have 1 interactive agent running on a given machine. If you tried to install more than one interactive agent on the same machine, it says

- ### > "An interactive session for this machine already exists, waiting till > reconnected".